# var foo = foo || alert(foo);

Tags: javascript, logic

Can someone explain what this does?

```
var foo = foo || alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `foo` is already defined and evaluates to true, it sets `foo = foo`, i.e. it does nothing.

If `foo` is defined but evaluates to false, it would popup whatever `foo` is (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, empty string, 0, NaN), but since `alert` returns nothing, `foo` will be set to `undefined`.

If `foo` is not yet defined, an exception will be thrown. (**Edit:** In your example, `foo` will always be defined because of the `var foo` declaration.)

Answer (score 4):

If `foo` evaluates to false (e.g. false, null or zero), the value after the `||` operator is also evaluated, and shows the value.

The `alert` method doesn't return a value, so `foo` will become undefined if it evaluated to false, otherwise it will be assigned it's own value.

Comment: Isn't it assigned?  It is an rvalue

Comment: `alert(foo)` returns undefined.

Comment: @Rocket: All documentation that I have found that specifies the return value (which the Mozilla docs doesn't), says that it has no return value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535933%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Rocket, @Guffa: Actually it's not *wrong* to say that `alert` returns `undefined`, since JavaScript implicitly returns `undefined` in the absence of a return value. Or in other words, it's not possible to differentiate between a function without a return value and one with a `return undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var foo;

if (foo)
    foo = foo;
else
    foo = alert(foo); // probably undefined
```

Comment: @Hogan: > *alert(foo); is an lvalue not an rvalue*.  What?